# Manejo de imagenes con URL invalida

Tags: flutter, imagen, http, get, null

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenos dias, una consulta, como manejan ustedes las imagenes con url invalidas, es decir existe la url en el endpoint, pero al momento de renderizar, genera error porque la url de la imagen no devuelve nada.  Esto lo maneje [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si existe un error cargue la imagen por defecto, pero aun asi me arroja error, al final tengo que realizar doble verificacion de si es valida la url, y de si existe la imagen. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tipo de error te da? Cuando quieres cargar la imagen por defecto. Yo lo hago como en la primera imagen que tienes usando el "imageErrorBuilder", y lo acabo de recrear exactamente igual y funciona como se espera. ¿Qué versión de flutter tienes?

[Aquí hice un vídeo corto usandolo](https://youtu.be/LxLL7pNgaDY)